# How do I establish communication between independent components in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-components

I have a *Nav* in which there are *two* pages representing two AngularJS components - `Home` and `About`. I want to pass `user` name from `Home` component to `About` component.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#!/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!/about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

I tried to establish the component communication using `bindings` with `<` but no luck. Basically, they are both independent components. How do I pass data from one component to another in this scenario.

I've created a working example using [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chilupa/pen/rNBmdxj). Could anyone please guide how to do it.

**Components and Route Config**

```
app.component("home", {
  template: `<h1>Home</h1>
              Hi {{$ctrl.user}}!`,
  controller: function HomeController() {
    this.user = "John.";
  }
});

app.component("about", {
  template: `<h1>About</h1>`,
  controller: function AboutController() {}
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
      template: "<home></home>"
    })
    .when("/about", {
      template: "<about></about>"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/home"
    });
});
```

Comment: Highly recommend using a service: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Yes. I've implemented it yesterday and was easy. @ChristopherMarshall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View data is destroyed when views change. Store data that needs to persist between views in a service:

```
app.service("appData", function() {
    var user;
    this.setUser= val => user = val;
    this.getUser= _ => user;
});
```

Use that service in the component controllers:

```
app.component("home", {
  template: `<h1>Home</h1>
              Hi {{$ctrl.user}}!`,
  controller: function HomeController(appData) {
    this.user = "John.";
    appData.setUser(this.user);
  }
});

app.component("about", {
  template: `<h1>About</h1>`,
  controller: function AboutController(appData) {
      this.user = appData.getUser();
  }
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I implemented. +1 to your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

@georgeawg already answered the question sufficiently. But I feel one should use sessionStorage when storing username or other userDetails because the date in the service gets erased when the user redirects to other pages. Hence storing it once in the sessionStorage can be very helpful.

```
// Create item:
var myObj = { username: 'admin', privilages: 'RAED' };
$window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(myObj));

// Read item:
var item = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem(key));
```

Comment: `sessionStorage` is nowhere related to my question. This answer seems irrelevant.